# Use of generic types in overloaded methods

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I have a generic method:

```
public bool DoSomething<T>(T item) where T: IBase
{
    return DoSomethingSpecific(item);
}

public bool DoSomethingSpecific(IBase item)
{
    return true;
}

public bool DoSomethingSpecific(IAdvanced item)
{
    return false;
}
```

Note that IAdvanced interface derives/inherits from IBase interface.

I have found that if I call DoSomething where the item is of type IAdvanced, it still always returns false. I don't understand this. I know that since IAdvanced is a type IBase (as it is a child of this interface), it may cause confusion between the 2 overloaded types of the DoSomethingSpecific method. However, as I understand with my limited C# knowledge, the IAdvanced method should be chosen here. This is an example of how I made this conclusion:

```
public class Advanced: IAdvanced
{

   public void CallMethod()
   {
      DoSomething(this);
   }
}
```

This results in a true value.

However, if I do:

```
public class Advanced: IAdvanced
{

    public void CallMethod()
    {
       DoSomethingSpecific(this);
    }
}
```

It returns false, which is what I would expect.

I have to say that I have never used generics before. I have attempted though, but always get stuck on a case like this, and then completely fail to see the point of using generics (besides data structures such as trees and linked lists).

This time I decided to come here for some advice. Is there a clear problem with what I am trying to do? Does it perhaps not make sense to try and do what I am busy doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as it knows, it's an IBase. The compiler needs to deside which method are you calling and that's why it's choosing that one always.

A dirty trick will be to do this:

```
public static bool DoSomething<T>(T item) where T: IBase
{
    var isAdvanced = typeof(IAdvanced).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
    return isAdvanced ? DoSomethingSpecific((IAdvanced)item) : DoSomethingSpecific(item);
}
```

Another way is to use Double-Dispatch/Visitor pattern:

```
public interface IDoSomethingVisitor {
    bool DoSomethingSpecific(IBase base);
    bool DoSomethingSpecific(IAdvanced adv);
}
```

The DoSomething Method will be in your IBase interface:

```
public interface IBase{
    void DoSomething(IDoSomethingVisitor visitor);
}
```

And in your implementations:

```
public class Base : IBase
{
   public bool DoSomething(IDoSomethingVisitor visitor)
   {
      visitor.DoSomething(this);
   }
}

public class Advanced : IAdvanced
{
   public bool DoSomething(IDoSomethingVisitor visitor)
   {
      visitor.DoSomething(this);
   }
}
```

In this case, the problem is solved using pure inheritance. The actual instance is the one that resolves which method to call. No ifs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will attempt this. I'm worried about performance in using typeof, but I guess I shouldn't pre-optimize

Comment: I'll provide a more complex option but a better design

Comment: Your suggestion of using the Double-Dispatch/Visitor pattern is pretty good. I have half implemented this. I have not thought of implemented the visitor, instead I have to repeatedly update my interface for each new derivation of the base class. Only saw this now after I accepted Tim S's answer. I think I may actually like this one better. I'll try it out!

Comment: The visitor works fantastically. I applied it to a case where my base class is abstract, so I just made the DoSomething method abstract, which forces me to create the public bool DoSomething(IDoSomethingVisitor visitor) for each concrete class. However, I was wondering, all of the methods will be exactly the same (with the keyword "this" referring to something else in each case). Is there no better way to do it, so that I don't have to implement this method for each concrete class?

Comment: It's the way because beside they all look the same, `this` have a different meaning and the method that is being called is a different one.

Comment: I accepted because of the visitor pattern by the way. Not too keen on doing the first "dirty" trick.

Comment: Denzil, do you mind explaining why you chose the visitor pattern over the super-clean solution of @Tim S.? What is the added value of the visitor here?

Comment: The problem with the "if" solution is that sometimes you have a proxy that represents a `IBase` that underneath is a IAdvanced, but as the proxy will just be `IBase`, it won't work. Using double-dispatch you leave the decision to the inheritance itself. Also, the "if" solution is provided in this answer too, at the beginning, as a dirty trick.

Comment: I that case, I would prefer `IBase` to have a property `IsAdvanced` so again you let the responsibility to the inheritance and not outside of it.

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce this, which means that something else is probably going on. I suspect you actually *meant* to say that it always returns *true*. That's what I see here:

```
using System;

public interface IBase {}
public interface IAdvanced : IBase {}

public class Base : IBase {}
public class Advanced : IAdvanced {}

class Test
{
    public static bool DoSomething<T>(T item) where T: IBase
    {
        return DoSomethingSpecific(item);
    }

    public static bool DoSomethingSpecific(IBase item)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool DoSomethingSpecific(IAdvanced item)
    {
        return false;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(new Base()));     // True
        Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(new Advanced())); // True
    }    
}
```

Now you also write:

> I know that since IAdvanced is a type IBase (as it is a child of this interface), it may cause confusion between the 2 overloaded types of the DoSomethingSpecific method. However, as I understand with my limited C# knowledge, the IAdvanced method should be chosen here.

Surely then you should *expect* `false` to be returned - whereas I expect `true` to be returned.

You see, the overload resolution within `DoSomething<T>` is determined when that method is compiled. That choice is made *once* - not once for every different `T`. So if you look in the compiled IL for `DoSomething<T>`, you'll *only* see a call to `DoSomethingSpecific(IBase)`, *never* `DoSomethingSpecific(IAdvanced)`. There's no polymorphism here.

As for how you can "fix" this - you'd need to explain in more detail what you *really* want to achieve. In particular, what would you want to happen if you had this code:

```
IBase x = new AdvancedImplementation();
DoSomething(x);
```

Here `T` would be `IBase`, but the *value* would refer to an implementation of `IAdvanced`. If you want `DoSomethingSpecific(IAdvanced)` to be executed in this case, and if you're using C# 4, then you can use dynamic typing:

```
public static bool DoSomething(IBase item)
{
    dynamic dynamicItem = item;
    // Dispatch dynamically based on execution-time type
    return DoSomethingSpecific(dynamicItem);
}
```

Note how the method doesn't need to be generic any more - it would give no benefit.

If, on the other hand, you want to decide which to call solely based on `T`, you'd need to use something like ivowiblo's solution.

Personally I would *try* to avoid both of these solutions - I usually find that this sort of thing is a symptom of a design which can be improved in other ways.

Comment: He's expecting false for Advanced

Comment: @ivowiblo: Well he's claiming that it *returns* false, but it clearly doesn't (see my example). I've added an edit explaining why expecting it to return false is forlorn hope.

Comment: Yes I'm expecting false. Did you not get false?? I get a false :/ I'll go through my code again

Comment: This happens because c# uses static binding, rather than dynamic. So as Jon said, the decision on which method to call is done at compile time, as opposed as runtime

Comment: I'd also like to add that my Advanced class looks like this: Advanced: Base, IAdvanced

Comment: @Denzil: I suspect you're actually calling `DoSomethingSpecific`, not `DoSomething`. If you were *expecting* false and you're *getting* false, why did you ask the question? You're not being clear between your expected and actual results - and it would *really* help if you'd show a short but complete console app which demonstrates the problem, similar to mine.

Comment: Oh sorry, I got confused by your answer. Yes, if I call DoSomething, I get true in one case, and false in the other. In the case where I call DoSomethingSpecific, I get true for both answers. Is this what is expected? I guess my knowledge on generics is lacking. But if this is what is expected then you have answered my question

Comment: @Denzil: No, you should get True in both cases if you call DoSomething, and True then False if you call DoSomethingSpecific. Please double-check your tests, and see my short but complete example and the explanation beneath it. It sounds like you've got confused between your *real* method names and the ones you've given in this post.

Comment: Yes, my tests match up with yours. Sorry about the previous confusion. As I said, it was a lack of knowledge on my part, and did not expect true in both cases for DoSomething. I have learnt something today from your answer. Really helpful thanks. And when I say I did not expect false in both cases, I realize that this was a mistake.

Comment: "You see, the overload resolution within DoSomething<T> is determined when that method is compiled. That choice is made once - not once for every different T" <- this cleared it up for me.

Comment: @Denzil: Goodo. One thing to learn from this: providing a short but *complete* example reduces the possibility for confusion when describing what happens :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I am struggling a bit with a design issue here, I realize. I'm trying to cut time by avoiding type checking, and was suspecting if I could handle it with overloading it would be quicker to execute, as it is in a rather tight performance spot. I'm interested in the dynamic solution, even though it may be slightly dodgy.

Comment: I see now that I mixed up the function names while commenting here, not smart :/ I'll fix it now... or not. I can't edit them

Comment: You could use the `dynamic` feature of C# to get the desired behaviour (see my answer for how to do that).

Comment: @jeroenh: Also as per my answer (near the end) ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would drop the compile-time check and make it runtime:

```
public bool DoSomething(IBase item)
{
    var itemAdvanced = item as IAdvanced;
    if (itemAdvanced != null)
        return DoSomethingSpecific(itemAdvanced);
    else
        return DoSomethingSpecific(item);
}
```

The reason is that if your caller only statically knows of the object as an `IBase`, but at runtime it's an `IAdvanced`, wouldn't it be preferred to treat it as an `IAdvanced`?  This is probably also the fastest way to do what you want.  I'd only go for the `dynamic` approach if you see a need to, e.g. because there could be a great number of different methods.

Comment: Maybe this didn't answer what I explicitly asked, but it definitely answered what I meant to ask. Thanks a lot, I'm going to use this. It seems clean and simple, and I'm sure it won't be too hard performance-wise.